# Convert timestamp to day-of-week string with date_format in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I keep on getting error, that I pass too many arguments and not sure why, as I am following the exact examples from:

```
command-629173529675356:9: error: too many arguments for method apply: (colName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column in class Dataset
val df_2 = date_format.withColumn("day_of_week", date_format(col("date"), "EEEE"))
```

My code:

```
val date_format = df_filter.withColumn("date", to_date(col("pickup_datetime")))
val df_2 = date_format.withColumn("day_of_week", date_format(col("date"), "EEEE"))
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: have you tried `dayofweek` function ?

Answer (score 1):

[`dayofweek`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#dayofweek(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is the function you're looking for, so something like this

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.dayofweek

date_format.withColumn("day_of_week", dayofweek(col("date")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You get your error because you named your first dataframe `date_format`, which is the same name as the Spark's built-in function you want to use. So when you call `date_format`, you're retrieving your dataframe instead of `date_format` built-in function.

To solve this, you should either rename your first dataframe:

```scala
val df_1 = df_filter.withColumn("date", to_date(col("pickup_datetime")))
val df_2 = df_1.withColumn("day_of_week", date_format(col("date"), "EEEE"))
```

Or ensure that you're calling right `date_format` by importing `functions` and then call `functions.date_format` when extracting day of week:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

val date_format = df_filter.withColumn("date", to_date(col("pickup_datetime")))
val df_2 = date_format.withColumn("day_of_week", functions.date_format(col("date"), "EEEE"))
```